# How to TOP CROP Image using PhotoView Android?

Tags: android, imageview, crop

I have 1 ImageView with layout_width & layout_height is match_parent, two of them is screen width and height size. I need display photo to fill full width and when image is higher than ImageView height, it can be scroll up and down. I'm using PhotoView library to zoom, scroll, tap... now i'm using centerCrop scale type but it is not solution i need. It show a part of center image and i need scroll up to view from beginning.

I tried lot of custom view extended ImageView to display Top Crop style but when i touch to image, it changed to default PhotoView scale type. It only work when not use PhotoViewAttacher

How i can make a Top Crop and scroll + zoom + touch... image by using PhotoView library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a TopCrop scale changing the CENTER_CROP scale under updateBaseMatrix() in PhotoViewAttacher of Chris Banes`s PhotoView.

Here is the code:

```
else if (mScaleType == ScaleType.CENTER_CROP) {
   float scale = Math.max(widthScale, heightScale);
    mBaseMatrix.postScale(scale, scale);
    //Changed dy = 0 for top crop
    mBaseMatrix.postTranslate((viewWidth - drawableWidth * scale) / 2F, 0);
```

Source: http://www.widecodes.com/fxSzNWPeVX/android-image-view-top-crop.html

---

Since I so that people are requesting more scaleTypes in ImageView: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58468 I added custom scale types to Chris Banes`s PhotoView.

I send a PR to him. Since I don't know if he will accept the PR(or when), you can get the project in my github: https://github.com/jonathanrz/PhotoView/ and add the aar to your project manually.

You can see an example of usage in CropTypeActivity in the sample project inside the library.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @bytecode77 I improved the answer. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Do you know if the underlying matrix can be translated with the default version of PhotoView?

Comment: @Niko I don't know, what do you need to do?

Comment: Achieve the same top crop feature but using the original PhotoView dependency.

Comment: @Niko some methods are private in PhotoView, so you will need to create a copy of PhotoView in your project to change the underlying matrix, but why do you need the original?

Comment: @Niko I made a PR with my changes to original PhotoView, I checked now I saw that someone is now maintening it, that's awesome news :), maybe my PR will be merged now. But I don't think that you will be able to update the matrix from outside PhotoView class :/

Comment: Got the solution for my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479400/android-photoview-setdisplaymatrix

Comment: @Niko I don't think it is necessary, SO collapses the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify PhotoView library, 
How about this solution using CustomAttacher class.
Inherit PhotoViewAttacher then override getDrawMatrix() method.

```
public class CustomAttacher extends PhotoViewAttacher {

    public CustomAttacher(ImageView imageView) {
        this(imageView, true);
    }

    public CustomAttacher(ImageView imageView, boolean zoomable) {
        super(imageView, zoomable);

    }

    @Override
    public Matrix getDrawMatrix() {
        Matrix mx = super.getDrawMatrix();
        float[] values = new float[9];
        mx.getValues(values);
        values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] = 0;
        mx.setValues(values);
        return mx;
    }

}
```