# Android PhotoView setDisplayMatrix

Tags: android

I am using https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView and trying to top crop it using `setDisplayMatrix` method.

Based on issue: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/issues/185

It should work, but I am not getting it to work. My `ImageView` has `android:scaleType="center"`defined in xml.

When should `setDisplayMatrix` be called in order to get it work right way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending the default `PhotoView` and overriding `setImageDrawable` did the trick for me.

```
@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    super.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    Matrix m = getDisplayMatrix();
    float[] values = new float[9];
    m.getValues(values);

    if (values[5] < 0.0f) {
        m.postTranslate(0, -2 * values[5]);
        setDisplayMatrix(m);
    }
}
```